# Problem accessing generic onboard SD card reader

Tags: boot, usb, mount, sd-card

I am using Jammy Jellyfish (fully updated) on a Toshiba Satellite L870-18V laptop using an Intel Core i3 dual core 4 thread processor and 8 GB of RAM.

I have long had problems accessing an SD card mounted into the onboard card reader. The boot up log was generated with the SD card and its adapter "fully home" in the onboard reader slot and package udisks2 is(!) installed and is the latest version.

I have just learned that as the system is using systemd I must use " journalctl -b " to view the boot up log. Doing so in Konsole I was able to find the following.

```
usb3-2: device desciptor read/64, error -71
usb3-2: device not responding to setup address      // *1
usb3-2: device not accepting address 5, error -71   // *2
usb3-2: device not accepting address 6, error -71   // *2
usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device      // *2
```

Further on in the log I found the following.

```
systemd[1]: Found device Multi-Card.
systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20090516388200000-0:0...
mount[632]: mount: /mnt/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20090516388200000-0:0: no medium found on /dev/sdb.
systemd[1]: mnt-usb\x2dGeneric\x2d_Multi\x2dCard_20090516388200000\x2d0:0.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.   // *1
systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20090516388200000-0:0   // *2
```

NOTE: The asterisks are my own notation and have the following meanings.

```
*1 The message text after usb3-2 or systemd[1] was displayed in yellow.
*2 The message text after usb3-2 or systemd[1] was displayed in red.
```

Finally, when I enter "dmesg | tail -20" I get the following output.

```
dmesg | tail -20
[ 2057.366833] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 124735360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2057.366891] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[ 2057.366898] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 124735360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2057.366902] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 15591920, async page read
[ 2057.455884] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[ 2057.455894] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32768 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2057.455898] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost async page write
[ 2072.248076] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 124735488 512-byte logical blocks: (63.9 GB/59.5 GiB)
[ 2072.255610]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2713.122097] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 124735488 512-byte logical blocks: (63.9 GB/59.5 GiB)
[ 2713.130090]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2734.992147] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[ 2734.992160] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 124735360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2734.992210] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[ 2734.992216] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 124735360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2734.992222] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 15591920, async page read
[ 2735.079520] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[ 2735.079528] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32768 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2735.079532] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost async page write
[ 2778.400046] usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
```

This seems to indicate that Kubuntu does recognise the card as a 64GB device, which it is. Kubuntu also seems to recognise that the card is located at sdb1.

However, when I try to mount the card to an empty directory (using either sdb or sdb1) I get the following output.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /home/kub/fred
mount: /home/kub/fred: no medium found on /dev/sdb.
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/kub/fred
mount: /home/kub/fred: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist.
```

Does the foregoing mean that the onboard card reader most probably has a hardware fault or is this a software fault that might(!) be fixed ? I should state that the "...error -71" messages appeared for the first time this morning.

Stuart

Comment: I would suggest everything points to the SD reader has a hardware issue. Have you tried more then 1 SD card?

Comment: Sadly, no as I cannot afford to buy another SD card and adapter for it (just in case the fault lies with the adapter).